# Send javascript variables (cookies) as Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, contact-form, contact-form-7

I'm building a javascript configurator for choosing the color and other aspects of a car, and I store the data  in cookies that are later shown to the user in a table with the pricing of each feature, how can I send these cookies as an email?

I have a solution in mind, im using wordpress, and I have contact form 7 plugin, if I could make a script to auto-fill the message field with javascript variables that would output the cookies to this hidden field, I could then send it to a chosen email using the plugin, my doubt is, I have no clue about how to do this, thats why im asking for your help, perhaps someone has been around for longer and has tried to fiddle with this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

Get the cookie value by `$.cookie("example")` and pass it to hidden field:

```
$('#hiddenFieldID').val($.cookie("example"));
```

You can set hidden field in the ContactForm7 admin area.

Comment: im already using the jquery-cookie plugin, i just needed to know how to output those cookies to the contact form 7 plugin so i could email them, i will try this, thank you so much :)